# Why is KNN much faster than decision tree?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, knn

Once in an interview, I encountered a question from the employer. He asked me why KNN classifier  is much faster than decision tree for example in letter recognition or in face recognition?

I had completely no idea at that time. So I want to know in which terms should I compare the two classification methods in speed performance? Thanks.

Comment: there are quite a few comparisons online

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following dataset: N samples, each has k attributes. In general :

 
1. naive KNN: O(1) [training Time] + O(NK) [query Time] = O (NK)

2. naive decision tree: O(N^2 * K * log(N)) [training Time] + O(log(N)) [query Time] = O(N^2 * K) -- Also for query time, we assume that the tree is balanced.

 
To calculate the complexities, I considered very simple implementation of each classifier. Already there are few improvements for implementing KNN and Decision Tree.

Comment: Very appreciate your answering. Could you explain a little bit more about the training time for each of the classifier? Thanks.

Comment: @Majid, can you please provide a reference for further reading?